# Access textbox value in a header in a master page to .aspx.vb page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I created a textbox and a submit button in header(User Control) included in a master page

and I want to use that textbox value after clicking submit in my .aspx.vb page.

How can i access that, as the vb page is loaded first and then master page is loading ?

Answer (score 0):

- The best way to communicate from UserControl to Page/MasterPage is using events
- The best way to communicate from MasterPage to Page is using events

On this way you don't hardlink UserControls with their Pages/MasterPages and the Page with it's Master.

Add an event to your UserControl that is raised when the user clicks the button, for example:

In UserControl of type `MyControl`:

```
public delegate void SubmittedHandler(MyControl ctrl);
public event SubmittedHandler Submitted;

protected void BtnCLick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Submitted(this);
}
```

Then add an handler to this event in your MasterPage, handle it and raise the Master's event again:

In Master's codebehind:

```
public delegate void MyControlSubmittedHandler(MyControl ctrl);
public event MyControlSubmittedHandler ControlSubmitted;

protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.MyControl1.Submitted += MyControlSubmitted;
}

protected void MyControlSubmitted(MyControl sender) {
    ControlSubmitted(sender);
}
```

Then add an handler to this event to your page:

In your Page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ((SiteMaster)Master).ControlSubmitted += MasterControlSubmitted;
}

protected void MasterControlSubmitted(MyControl sender){
    // do whatever you need to do
}
```

If you only need to access the `TextBox` from the page and you don't need to handle the click-event, you could also use properties to achieve this:

- add a public property f.e. `MyControlText` in your `UserControl` that get/set the `TextBox.Text` property
- add a public property f.e. `MyControlText` in your `Master` that get/set your UserControl's `MyControlText` property
- Now you can get/set this property from your page in this way:
  `((SiteMaster)Master).MyControlText = "Hello World";`

Answer (score 0):

> TextBox Val = (TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("TextBoxID");